# Should a column of user votes be updated in real-time or once-a-day, and how?

Tags: mysql, database-design

On one of my sites, users can vote on each other.  I have a `Votes` table where each row corresponds to a vote given.

I want to start showing users their total vote score, which is simply the sum of the votes they have received in that `Votes` table.  Should I calculate this in real-time, or should I calculate it once-a-day.  What's the "best practice" for this type of scenario (assuming hundreds of thousands of votes and growing)?

In real-time is easy enough, but the once-a-day is not so simple.  I'm assuming I would need to do a Cron Job, but how exactly would I go about doing this?  I know I would need to iterate through each user and do a sum of the votes they have received in that `Votes` table, but do I need to do a full sum each and every day starting from the very first vote and save that, or should I only add the **new** votes (since the last update) to the existing sum and save that instead?

If it's the latter, then how exactly would I do that and keep track of everything so that no votes are missed nor added twice?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of dealing with this is [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization), which basically means storing data that could be determined by a query. Not only is it the only really [scalable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable) solution, it is fairly simple and results in excellent performance. Here's how you implement it:

Add a `total_votes` column to the `users` table and keep it correct by a trigger that fires when the voting data changes.

Something like this:

```
delimiter //

create trigger vote_trigger
after insert on votes
for each row
begin
    update users set
    total_votes = total_votes + 1
    where users.user_id = new.user_id;
end; //

delimiter ;
```

Create other similar triggers for row deletion and row update.

Initially, run a query to populate all the values, something like this **run only once ever** while your system is off-line or in read-only mode:

```
update users set
total_votes = (select count(*) from votes where user_id = users.user_id);
```

but executing this query, the trigger(s) will keep the values of `total_votes` correct (ie in-sync with the `votes` table).

Comment: Interesting.  But if I understand the trigger correctly, is it recalculating everyone's total vote every time a single new vote is made?  If so, isn't that very inefficient, or am I understanding it incorrectly (e.g. I'm not sure what `new.user_id` is)?

Comment: Whenever you denormalize, which is a legitimate performance optimization, be sure to write tools to ensure your duplicate values stay in sync. If you don't do this, occasionally you will have drift between the cached value and the actual value.

Comment: @tadman:  I'm not sure I understand what you mean, could you please provide an example?  Thanks.

Bohemian:  Did you receive my question above?  Thanks.

Comment: In this particular case I mean you need to create a way to populate `total_votes` with the correct counts. It may be the case that once in a while you will have incorrect values in that column. The example initial query is one example of how to do this, but there are likely other more efficient ways.

Comment: @Programmer No - the trigger is incrementing the `total_votes` value for the user who just had a vote inserted for him/her